# What is contract type in solidity

Tags: types, solidity

I just started learning solidity recently.
I don't understand why and when should I declare type as contract name.
Sometimes we use contract type for array, and sometimes we use it as address type.
I don't get it how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you prefix the contract type with the `new` keyword or not.

**With** the `new` keyword, you're passing constructor params (in the example below two strings) and deploying new contract.

**Without** the `new` keyword, you're instantiating a pointer to an already deployed contract (in the example below on the address `0x123`) and can invoke its `public` and `external` functions.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Hello {
    constructor(string memory text1, string memory text2) {}
}

contract World {
    function foo() external {
        // deploying new contract
        new Hello("constructor", "params");

        // pointing to an already deployed contract
        Hello(address(0x123));
    }
}
```